# list index out of range is from book

Tags: python

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://new.cpc.com.tw/division/mb/oil-more4.aspx'

html = requests.get(url).text
sp = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
data = sp.find_all('span', {'id':'Showtd'})
rows = data[0].find_all('tr')

prices = list()
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    if len(cols[1].text) > 0:
       item = [cols[0].text, cols[1].text,cols[2].text, cols[3].text]
        prices.append(item)
for p in prices:
    print(p)
```

I receive an error as follows:

```
>IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call >last)
><ipython-input-4-0e950be61842> in <module>()
 >    10 sp = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
 >    11 data = sp.find_all('span', {'id':'Showtd'})
>---> 12 rows = data[0].find_all('tr')
 >    13 
 >   14 prices = list()

>IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Do you want us to fix the error?

Comment: Are you sure that `data` is not empty? What do you get in the variable `data` when you debug your code?

Comment: len(data) is zero.

Comment: This problem has been solved
Is ssl problem  thx

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
url = 'http://new.cpc.com.tw/division/mb/oil-more4.aspx'
```

to

```
url = 'https://new.cpc.com.tw/division/mb/oil-more4.aspx'
```

Otherwise the actual response says something about an SSL redirect (no tables were returned at all, nor was the page you expected). Works for me